# React Native - Android position absolute buttons are untappable

Tags: react-native

I have a react native component that handles comunication between two peers using WebRTC.

Everything works perfectly on ios but on android the buttons are unclickable and i am pretty sure its because of the position:absolute, the buttons rendering somewhere behind a element and because of that they are untappable.

My question is ... what am i doing wrong? Why are they rendering but they are untappable on android?

The buttons are: End call positioned center bottom and switch camera positioned right bottom.

PS: I removed most of the component logic as it was irelevant to the question.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { RTCView } from 'react-native-webrtc';
    import WebSocketWrapper from '../components/generic/WebSocketWrapper/WebSocketWrapper';
    import { Image, StyleSheet, View, Text, Platform, ActivityIndicator, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
    import RNSecureStorage, { ACCESSIBLE } from 'rn-secure-storage';
    import WebRtcPeer from 'react-native-kurento-utils';
    import { COLORS } from '../styles/colors';
    import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import Toast from 'react-native-root-toast';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
    import IconIonicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
    import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import logger from '#/logging.service';
    import utils from '#/utils.service';

    const BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE = 60;
    const ICON_CIRCLE_SIZE = BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE / 2;
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      rtcViewsContainer: {},
      remoteView: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#000000'
      },
      selfView: {
        position: 'absolute',
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        left: 16,
        bottom: 32,
        borderWidth: 0.5
      },
      textContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 32,
        width: '100%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      },
      introductionText: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        fontSize: 13,
        lineHeight: 22,
        textAlign: 'center'
      },
      logo: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        height: 70,
        width: 150
      },
      logoContainer: {
        height: 70,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      },
      endCallIconContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 100,
        bottom: 32,
        width: BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row'
      },
      endCallIconTouchable: {
        width: BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE,
        height: BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE,
        borderRadius: BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE / 2,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        zIndex: 110,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      switchCameraIconTouchable: {
        width: BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE,
        height: BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE,
        borderRadius: BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE / 2,
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
        zIndex: 110,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      },
      switchCameraIcon: {
        width: BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE,
        height: BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE
      },
      endCallIcon: {
        alignSelf: 'center'
      }
    });

    export default class VideoCallIdentification extends Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
      };

      displayRTCViews() {
        return !!(this.state.remoteURL && this.state.videoURL);
      }

      getText() {
        if (this.state.CALL_STATE === this.CALL_STATES.FINISHED_CALL) {
          return 'Please wait ...';
        } else if (this.state.REGISTERED_STATE === this.CALL_STATES.REGISTERED) {
          return 'An agent will be with you soon. You will be prompted to give access to your microphone and camera in order for the video call to proceed!';
        }
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.stopCommunication();
      }
      getRemoveViewDimensions() {
        return {
          width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
          height: Dimensions.get('window').height
        };
      }
      onSocketError(e) {
        logger.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Socket Erorr!', e);
        utils.toast('An unexpected error has ocurred!');
        this.stopWebRtc();
        this.props.navigation.navigate('CompleteAccountPage');
      }
      getEndCallBarSize() {
        return {
          left: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2 - BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE / 2,
          height: BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE
        };
      }
      getSwitchCameraBarSize() {
        return {
          right: 32,
          height: BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE
        };
      }
      changeCamera() {
        this.webRtcConnection.toggleCamera();
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <View
            style={{ marginTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, marginBottom: 0, flex: 1, width: '100%', ...this.getRemoveViewDimensions() }}
            containerStyle={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', ...this.getRemoveViewDimensions() }}
          >
            <SafeAreaView style={{ ...this.getRemoveViewDimensions(), position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}>
              {this.displayRTCViews() ? (
                <View>
                  <View style={{ ...styles.rtcViewsContainer, ...this.getRemoveViewDimensions() }}>
                    <RTCView streamURL={this.state.remoteURL} style={{ ...styles.remoteView, ...this.getRemoveViewDimensions() }} />
                    <RTCView streamURL={this.state.videoURL} style={styles.selfView} />
                  </View>
                  <View style={{ ...styles.endCallIconContainer, ...this.getEndCallBarSize() }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.endCallIconTouchable} onPress={() => this.stopCommunication(true).bind(this)}>
                      <Icon style={styles.endCallIcon} size={ICON_CIRCLE_SIZE} name="call-end" color="#ffffff" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{ ...styles.endCallIconContainer, ...this.getSwitchCameraBarSize() }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.switchCameraIconTouchable} onPress={() => this.changeCamera(true)}>
                      <IconIonicons style={styles.endCallIcon} size={BTN_CIRCLE_SIZE} name="ios-reverse-camera" color="#ffffff" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </View>
              ) : (
                <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                  <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                    <Image source={require('../assets/images/logoAndNameColored.png')} style={styles.logo} resizeMode="contain" />
                  </View>
                  <Text style={styles.introductionText}>{this.getText()}</Text>
                  <ActivityIndicator style={{ marginTop: 22 }} size="large" color={COLORS.APP_PURPLE} />
                </View>
              )}

              <WebSocketWrapper
                ref={ref => {
                  if (!this.state.socket) {
                    this.setState({ socket: ref });
                  }
                }}
                onError={this.onSocketError.bind(this)}
                onOpen={this.onSocketOpen.bind(this)}
                url={this.state.socketUrl}
                onMessage={this.onmessage.bind(this)}
              />
            </SafeAreaView>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    VideoCallIdentification.propTypes = {
      navigation: PropTypes.object
    };
```

Comment: Try giving `pointerEvents: 'box-none'` style to absolute positioned parent view. In your case `SafeAreaView`

Comment: There is a known issue in android where overflowing components touch events may not work properly. If your buttons are actually outside your absolute positioned parent view, using the above style will resolve your issue

Comment: Thank you for  your suggestion. I  pulled out the buttons from SafeAreaVIew and i put them at sibbling level, i also set pointerEvents: box-none on the SaveAreaView, but the buttons continue to be unresponsive.